# How to use hourly and minute timeframes in Lightweight charts TradingView?

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api, lightweight-charts

In the examples **[Lightweight charts TradingView](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs)** show plotting on a daily timeframe, but I can't figure out how to correctly pass data to setData in order to use hourly and minute timeframes.

Please tell me.

```
import { createChart } from 'lightweight-charts';

const chart = createChart(container);

const areaSeries = chart.addAreaSeries();
areaSeries.setData([
    { time: '2018-12-22', value: 32.51 },
    { time: '2018-12-23', value: 31.11 },
    { time: '2018-12-24', value: 27.02 },
    { time: '2018-12-25', value: 27.32 },
    { time: '2018-12-26', value: 25.17 },
    { time: '2018-12-27', value: 28.89 },
    { time: '2018-12-28', value: 25.46 },
    { time: '2018-12-29', value: 23.92 },
    { time: '2018-12-30', value: 22.68 },
    { time: '2018-12-31', value: 22.67 },
]);

const candlestickSeries = chart.addCandlestickSeries();
candlestickSeries.setData([
    { time: '2018-12-22', open: 75.16, high: 82.84, low: 36.16, close: 45.72 },
    { time: '2018-12-23', open: 45.12, high: 53.90, low: 45.12, close: 48.09 },
    { time: '2018-12-24', open: 60.71, high: 60.71, low: 53.39, close: 59.29 },
    { time: '2018-12-25', open: 68.26, high: 68.26, low: 59.04, close: 60.50 },
    { time: '2018-12-26', open: 67.71, high: 105.85, low: 66.67, close: 91.04 },
    { time: '2018-12-27', open: 91.04, high: 121.40, low: 82.70, close: 111.40 },
    { time: '2018-12-28', open: 111.51, high: 142.83, low: 103.34, close: 131.25 },
    { time: '2018-12-29', open: 131.33, high: 151.17, low: 77.68, close: 96.43 },
    { time: '2018-12-30', open: 106.33, high: 110.20, low: 90.39, close: 98.10 },
    { time: '2018-12-31', open: 109.87, high: 114.69, low: 85.66, close: 111.26 },
]);
```

Answer (score 6):

From the [documentation](https://tradingview.github.io/lightweight-charts/docs/api#time), we see this about the `Time` type:

> Values can be a UTCTimestamp, a BusinessDay, or a business day string
> in ISO format.

As their names suggest, BusinessDay and business day string don't seem to work for timeframes lower than a day, this is why `date` strings like `YYYY-MM-DD` work but `datetime` strings like `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM` don't. You will need to use `UTCTimestamp`.

Note: `UTCTimestamp` is a timestamp in seconds, not milliseconds.

Answer (score 5):

```js
lineSeries.setData([
    { time: Date.parse('2019-04-11 09:43')/1000, open: 180.34, high: 180.99, low: 178.57, close: 179.85 },
    { time: Date.parse('2019-04-11 09:44')/1000, open: 180.82, high: 181.40, low: 177.56, close: 178.75 },
    { time: Date.parse('2019-04-11 09:45')/1000, open: 175.77, high: 179.49, low: 175.44, close: 178.53 },
    { time: Date.parse('2019-04-11 09:46')/1000, open: 178.58, high: 182.37, low: 176.31, close: 176.97 },
    { time: Date.parse('2019-04-11 09:47')/1000, open: 177.52, high: 180.50, low: 176.83, close: 179.07 }
]);
```

this works for me.

Comment: it works for drawing but not for hover.

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me if I'm not well understood, I'm using google translate...

I was all afternoon with the same problem, I managed to find the solution here

https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/issues/477

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).